# Получение в js списка значений, а не списка названий объектов

Tags: javascript, jsp

В jsp определяется значение

```
  <script type="application/javascript">
    var dataList= "${data.dataList}";
  </script>
```

В подключенном js выбираем

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log(dataList);
}
```

В консоли в итоге

```
[ru.test.TestClass@253d1594, ru.test.TestClass@59cfed2c, ru.test.TestClass@525614c0, ru.test.TestClass@47381287]
```

Чего я делаю не так? Мне нужны значения списка объектов. Как обработать именно список значений?

Comment: возможно, переопределить метод toString у Вашего TestClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущей реализации у вас вызывается дефолтный метод toString объекта dataList, который, судя по всему есть объект класса ArrayList.

Для того, чтобы осуществить задуманное, вам надо:

- либо создать класс от ArrayList, и переопределить метод toString
- либо сконвертировать dataList в строку в виде JSON (либо в вид jsного массива), а только потом передавать ее в jsp
- либо обойти dataList прямо в jsp

Здесь есть все примеры: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array

Comment: Отличные примеры. Нашел ещё хорошие вот здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040719/6649819